# Store approver email to record

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, approval-process

Is there a way to capture and store the record's current/incoming approver email to the record itself via flow every time the record is submitted and reassigned?

Comment: Why would you need to capture the email when the Approval History gives you the Assigned To, Actual Approver and Overall Status?

Comment: I'm trying to create a time-based workflow to send a reminder email to the current approver and thought creating a custom email field so that the email will be sent to the right approver if the approver is reassigned